# are the predicates $\forall x P(x) \land Q(x)$ and $\forall x(P(x) \land Q(x))$, the same?

Tags: notation, predicate-logic

are the predicates $\forall x P(x) \land Q(x)$   and    $\forall x(P(x) \land Q(x))$, the same?

Comment: In the first one you have a free variable, so no. The parsing of the first one is $(\forall x P(x)) \wedge Q(x)$, with $x$ free for $Q$. The second one is a sentence (no free variables).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin This looks very much like an answer to the question :\

Comment: Not; the second one means: "Everything is both Black and Round" while the first one reads: "Everything is Black and **it** is Round" that can be true or false depending on what the pronoun "it" refer to.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some in-house parsing rule, no, they aren’t the same.

The natural parsing of the first is that it is
$$\Bigl( \forall xP(x)\Bigr)\wedge Q(x).$$
The $\forall x$ only bounds the $P(x)$, so this formula has $x$ as a free variable (it appears unbounded in the second part of the conjunction).

On the other hand, the second formula is
$$\forall x\Bigl( P(x)\wedge Q(x()\Bigr)$$
which has no free variables (is a sentence): $x$ is bound by $\forall x$ in all its occurrences.

Since the second formula is a sentence (no free variables) but the first formula has a free variable, they are not the same.

(Again, unless you have a parsing rule that gives $\wedge$ precedence so that when parsing the first formula you would first associate $P(x)\wedge Q(x)$, and then apply the quantifier.)